# Realistically, what pthreads functionality is generally used?

Tags: posix, pthreads

I'm working on the POSIX subsystem of my operating system project, and I've reached the point where I would like to work on pthreads support. However, I'm not certain about the extent to which I should implement them.

What is the most-used pthreads functionality? Is there anything I could safely "just stub out" for now and implement it when we port an application that requires it? My research so far points to the basic thread operations (create, join, etc...) - that's quite obvious - and mutex support. Realistically speaking, do applications use much more than this?

I guess I'm just trying to figure out how little I can get away with while still having a working implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest a bare bones pthread implementation cover the following functions (with "`pthread_`" prefixes removed):

- *basic thread operations*
  `create`, `exit`, `join`, `detach`, `self`, `equal`, and "`attr`" support of joinability/detachability
- *process integration*
  `atfork`, `kill` and `sigmask`
- *synchronization primitives*
  `cond` and `mutex` functions (default attributes only -- nothing fancy!), possibly omitting `cond_timedwait`

Take a look at the SUSv6 entry on [`<pthread.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/pthread.h.html), which I link in preference to SUSv7 because version 6 has more option groups called out in this header.  I composed the above list by striking any optional features, and then dropping other sets of functionality that my personal history and observation suggest are inessential (e.g., thread-specific data) or both inessential and dangerous (e.g., thread cancellation). :)

Comment: I ended up here while trying to figure out where to start, learning about pthreads: was really useful, helped me know which manpages to go to first! Not really relevant to the original question, but… good answer for *my* unrelated purposes as well! Woo :3

Answer (score 5):

You will definitely need to support mutexes and conditon variables, because threading would be unuseable without them, and they are both widely used. I suppose you could get away without supporting semaphores (which aren't part of pthreads, I think), but I can't imagine doing any serious MT work without them.

It might be interesting to look at the next proposed C++ standard which will [support threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Threading_facilities) and implement the features that it requires. If your OS can support future Standard C++ programs, it would be in pretty good shape.

Comment: +1 to revoke the downvote (downvoter: any reason?). Thanks for the answer, and especially for the C++ link. We plan to use C++ for our native API, so you unintentionally pointed me to relevant information for a totally different area.

Comment: @Neil, one could implement semaphores in terms of `cond` vars and `mutex`es, to address the lack of "realtime semaphore" support.

Comment: @pilcrow indeed, but it seems a bit of a shame to make everyone re-implement such  a commonly used feature

Comment: POSIX requires `sem_post` to be async signal safe, and no other synchronization functions are specified as async signal safe, so semaphores cannot be implemented as library routine on top of mutexes and condition variables unless the latter are known to use reentrant implementations.